# How to display counter value as 2 digits in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I am using angularjs timer to build a countdown display.

The timer directive returns value of hours, minutes and seconds as integer.
Means, 1,2,3,.... But I want to display these values as 2 digits.
like, 01,02,03,04,......

Is there any filter or directive to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would like to create a simple custom [AngularJS filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter).

> Filters are used for formatting data displayed to the user.

**Usage**

```
{{value | counterValue}}
```

**Filter**

```
app.filter('counterValue', function(){
   return function(value){
     value = parseInt(value);
      if(!isNaN(value) && value >= 0 && value < 10)
         return "0"+ valueInt;
      return "";
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The alternative to the filter would be the custom directive:

**Usage**

```
<li ng-repeat="item in array">
    <digit content="item"></digit>
</li>
```

**Directive**

```
.directive('digit', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            content: '='
        },
        link: function (scope) {
            if (scope.content < 10) {
                scope.zero = "0";
            } else {
                scope.zero = "";
            }
        },
        transclude: true,
        template: '{{zero}}{{content}}'
    };
});
```